# Connecting multiple vlans to a vlan compatible device

Tags: virtual-machines, switch, vlan

We have an HP V1910 switch.

Connected to this is an EXSi host with 4 vswitchs each with a VLAN assigned (1-4) connected to one external nic.
Also attached to the HP switch is a SAN file server which is has 2 VLAN compatible NICs.

The port the EXSi is connected to is set to hybrid and has VLAN 1-4 set as tagged with VLAN 1 as the default.

What do I need to do to setup the ports for the SAN so VLANS 1-4 (and no others) have full access to it?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which of these is the "VLAN unaware device"?  I'm really hoping it's not the V1910.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's a little unclear, can I try to clarify, let me know if I've got this wrong.

- Your ESXi server has 4 physical NICs, you've created 4 vSwitches,
  each with (at least) one Port Group and each Port Group is VLAN tagged.
- All four NICS connect are into the same physical switch.
- Also connected, by two NICS, to the same physical switch is a SAN box.
- You want all Port Groups to be capable of connecting to the SAN.

If so then you simply need to configure your all 6 appropriate physical switch ports to act as 5 trunks carrying the relavant VLANs and then setup your SAN box to have one two-port two trunk, both carrying all four VLANs and setup IP interfaces for each trunked VLAN.

That said I have to say I'm a little concerned/confused by a few things;

- Why do you want each VLAN to connect to the SAN - or is it a actually NAS really, that'd make sense, SAN protocols to each port isn't likely to.
- Why the 'one-VLAN-per-NIC' thing? If you lose a cable you lose a whole vswitch - why not create either two vSwitches with two Port Groups (one per VLAN) and add both physical NICs to the vSwitch or one big vSwitch with four physical NICS and four Port Groups - either way you'll be able to survive a cable failure - you'd have to create port groups on the physical switch by the way to support this.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look at implementing your suggestion on the V-LANs.